# db-migrate insert data from csv

Tags: node.js, postgresql, csv, serverless, dbmigrate

I need to insert data in to my postgresql via db-migrate for my serverless app. So I have 4 table and each table has it's own csv data. Due to the number of record, I need to do it automatically, any advice? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

- create a lambda that will use `db-migrate` to perform whatever operation you need to do
- install [serverless-scriptable-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-scriptable-plugin)
- invoke the function you created immediately after each deploy (by literally running `serverless invoke -f yourfunction`)